# nav-pills url is lost at page refresh

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I encounter following problems when using bs4 toggled nav-pills wrapped inside a nav tabs submenu:

1. next url doesn't load pill with id option2: http://localhost/test#option2 although if I click on it it switches to that pill.
2. When I am on pill with id option2 and I do page refresh it gets back to first pill - the one with id option1
3. I need to have a functional link for each pill which should open that specific pill and should be persistent at page refresh - I think it is called deep linking but examples I found are either different or old.

   ```
   <nav>
       <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" >
           <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" id="nav-menu1-tab" href="#">menu1</a>
           <a class="nav-item nav-link  active" id="nav-menu2-tab" href="#nav-menu2">active-tab</a>
           <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" id="nav-menu3-tab" href="#">menu3</a>
       </div>
   </nav>


   <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
       <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-menu2"></div>

       <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-option1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#option1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-option1" aria-selected="true">option1</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" id="pills-option2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#option2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-option2" aria-selected="false">option2</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
           <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="option1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-option1-tab">option1...</div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="option2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-option2-tab">option2...</div>
       </div>

   </div>
   ```